# And operator argument evaluation in C++

Tags: c++

How does and operator evaluates its arguments. I have a code to check whether a graph is cyclic or not. In this code there is an and condition in an if statement. And I think, to the best of what I can make out is, that it terminates at the first encounter of a false expression without evaluating the second expression at all.

This is the code

```
bool Graph::isCyclicUtil(int v, bool *visited, bool *recStack){
    if (visited[v] == false){
            // Mark the current node as visited 
            visited[v] = true;
            recStack[v] = true;

            // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
            list<int>::iterator i;
            for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); i++){
     -------->**This and cond**if (!visited[*i] && isCyclicUtil(*i, visited, recStack))
                            return true;
                    else if (recStack[*i])
                            return true;
            }
    }
    recStack[v] = false;    // remove the vertex from the recursion stack
    return false;
}

void Graph::printRecStack(bool *recStack){
    cout << "\n \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++){
            if (recStack[i])
                    cout <<i<< "\n";
    }
    return;
}


bool Graph::isCyclic(){
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited and not part of recursion stack
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    bool *recStack = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++){
            visited[i] = false;
            recStack[i] = false;
    }

    // Call the recursive helper function to detect cycle in different
    // DFS trees.
    if (isCyclicUtil(0,visited, recStack)){
            printRecStack(recStack);
            return true;
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < V; i++){
            if (isCyclicUtil(i, visited, recStack))
                    printRecStack(recStack);
                    return true;
    }*/
    return false;
}
```

Please observe the and condition inside the if statement in isCyclicUtil function.

If you take a simple graph as a test case like this one:

```
0->1
1->2
2->0
2->3
3->3
```

And call ***isCyclicUtil*** for ***0***, the first ***3*** values in ***recStack*** comes out to be true. Which should have not been the case if the second expression was also evaluated in the ***if statement***. Because call to ***node 2*** will reach for its ***child 0***. But since the loop started from 0, 0 is already visited, so ***recStack[0***] should be initialized to false. But this does not happens, and all of them come out to be true. As if the ***and*** condition terminated as soon as it encountered ***visited[0]*** to be true, without even calling ***isCyclicUtil(0,visited,recStack***) again.

Comment: Search the web for "short circuit evaluation". Note that this only applies to built-in operators. If you overload these operators, this is disabled and they behave like regular functions.

Comment: Any C++ book or tutorial will explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. This is called [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and is a feature of many programming languages.